# How to add computed observable to knockoutjs mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using the mapping plugin to create my client side view model based on an object that gets sent from the server. The object is basic address information ie: address1, address2, city, state, postal, ect...

Once the view model is bound, I want a google maps canvas to update if the user changes the address. I created a computed observable that checks the values entered and calls a map update function. I had this working before when I wasn't using the mapping plugin, ie model was defined locally, but once I introduced mapping I wasn't able to append the computed observable to the view model.

I tried following the instructions from the mapping plugin [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), but the computed observable isn't triggering updates. I have a custom mapping that calls a mapModel which contains the computed observable as in the examples, but no updates.

Any ideas?

```
$.getJSON("@Url.RouteUrl("
ContactUs_default ", new { action = "
GetPageModel ",  Model.BusinessID})", function(result) {
    //create map property
    result.Data.Map = null;
    var mapping = {
        'Map': {
            create: function(options) {
                return new mapModel(options.data);
            }
        }
    };

    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.Data, mapping);    

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});

var mapModel = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.Map = ko.computed(function() {
        var address = "";
        var enteredElements = 0;

        if (this.Address1 != helpText) {
            address += " " + this.Address1;
            enteredElements++;
        }

        if (this.Address2 != helpText) {
            address += " " + this.Address2;
        }

        if (this.City != helpText) {
            address += " " + this.City;
            enteredElements++;
        }

        if (this.State != helpText) {
            address += " " + this.County;
            enteredElements++;
        }

        if (this.PostalCode != helpText) {
            address += " " + this.Postal;
        }
        alert("hi");

        //only upate map if enough data has been entered to give accruate location
        if (enteredElements >= 3) {
            MYMAP.placeMarkers(address);
        }
    }, this);
};​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send your data through the mapping plugin, all of your properties will become observables.

This means that you need to access them as a function like like:

```
    if (this.Address1() != helpText) {
        address += " " + this.Address1();
        enteredElements++;
    }
```

When you access them as observables inside of a computed observables, then it will create a dependency.  So, currently your computed observable would get initially evaluated, but it would never update again, as it does not access the value of any observables.

Comment: Made that change but now I get a "Contact:340Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'Address1'" error pointing to the computed observable.

Comment: Looking a it the mapModel in the chrome js debugger, the properties of it are "Map" and  "__ko_mapping__". How can access the other properties of the model set by the mapping plugin?

Comment: Here is a fiddle that maybe you can modify to demonstrate something closer to your scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RUsp2/.  I am not sure what your data looks like exactly.  It looks like your results data has a `Map` property, but also that you are creating a `Map` computed observable as a child of it.

Comment: Finally got it! The results.data contains just the properties, address1, city, ect..., it did not have a map property. That was just a computed property I wanted created on the client side. I changed the custom mapping from 'Map' to 'Data' since 'Data' contained all the properties, and on ko.mapping.fromJS I passed in result rather then result.Data. Then I had the issue of the bound fields just saying Object rather then the actual value,  until in the html I added a  "with: Data" binding to the containing element. Here's the js fiddle of my current code http://jsfiddle.net/JPS5s/2/